# How to use sed to replace all ips in a file if the first 3 octets match

Tags: bash, sed

Ubuntu 16.04 with GNU bash, version 4.4.0

I need to post my dmesg but before I do this, I want to remove all destination ips 
and replace them with xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

The first 3 octets are the same but the last octet is different like so:

example: DST=123.12.12.145

`sed -i 's/DST=123.12.12.???/DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/g' filename`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -i -E 's/DST=123\.12\.12\.[0-9]{1,3}/DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/g' file
```

See an [online demo](http://rextester.com/HDLK61148)

Note that `.` chars should be escaped if you need to match literal dots.

The `[0-9]{1,3}` POSIX ERE compatible pattern (enabled with `-E`) will match 1, 2 or 3 digits.

To make sure you only match 3 digits at the end that are not followed with other digits, and that you are matching `DST` and not `ADST`, you may try adding word boundaries, `\<` and `\>`:

```
's/\<DST=123\.12\.12\.[0-9]{1,3}\>/DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/g'
   ^^                           ^^
```

Comment: You probably want to match `[0-9]{1,3}` to handle all 256 IPs with this netmask.

Comment: @randomir Yes, that is what I meant to write, I am still drinking my morning coffee :)